# Long running Mysql Query on Indexes and sort by clause

Tags: mysql

I have a very long running MySql query. The query simply joins two tables which are very huge

bizevents - Nearly 34 Million rows
bizevents_actions - Nearly 17 million rows

Here is the query:

```
 select
   bizevent0_.id as id1_37_,
   bizevent0_.json as json2_37_,
   bizevent0_.account_id as account_3_37_,
   bizevent0_.createdBy as createdB4_37_,
   bizevent0_.createdOn as createdO5_37_,
   bizevent0_.description as descript6_37_,
   bizevent0_.iconCss as iconCss7_37_,
   bizevent0_.modifiedBy as modified8_37_,
   bizevent0_.modifiedOn as modified9_37_,
   bizevent0_.name as name10_37_,
   bizevent0_.version as version11_37_,
   bizevent0_.fired as fired12_37_,
   bizevent0_.preCreateFired as preCrea13_37_,
   bizevent0_.entityRefClazz as entityR14_37_,
   bizevent0_.entityRefIdAsStr as entityR15_37_,
   bizevent0_.entityRefIdType as entityR16_37_,
   bizevent0_.entityRefName as entityR17_37_,
   bizevent0_.entityRefType as entityR18_37_,
   bizevent0_.entityRefVersion as entityR19_37_
 from
   BizEvent bizevent0_
 left outer join BizEvent_actions actions1_ on
   bizevent0_.id = actions1_.BizEvent_id
 where
   bizevent0_.createdOn >= '1969-12-31 19:00:01.0'
   and (actions1_.action <> 'SoftLock'
        and actions1_.targetRefClazz = 'com.biznuvo.core.orm.domain.org.EmployeeGroup'
        and actions1_.targetRefIdAsStr = '1'
        or actions1_.action <> 'SoftLock'
        and actions1_.objectRefClazz = 'com.biznuvo.core.orm.domain.org.EmployeeGroup'
        and actions1_.objectRefIdAsStr = '1')
 order by
    bizevent0_.createdOn;
```

Below are the table definitions -- As you see i have defined the indexes well enough on these two tables on all the search columns plus the sort column. But still my queries are running for very very long time. Appreciate any more ideas either with respective indexing.

-- bizevent definition

```
 CREATE TABLE `bizevent` (
   `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
   `json` longtext,
   `account_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `createdBy` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   `createdon` datetime(3) DEFAULT NULL,
   `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `iconCss` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
   `modifiedBy` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   `modifiedon` datetime(3) DEFAULT NULL,
   `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `version` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `fired` bit(1) NOT NULL,
   `preCreateFired` bit(1) NOT NULL,
   `entityRefClazz` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `entityRefIdAsStr` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `entityRefIdType` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
   `entityRefName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `entityRefType` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
   `entityRefVersion` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `IDXk9kxuuprilygwfwddr67xt1pw` (`createdon`),
    KEY `IDXsf3ufmeg5t9ok7qkypppuey7y` (`entityRefIdAsStr`),
    KEY `IDX5bxv4g72wxmjqshb770lvjcto` (`entityRefClazz`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

-- bizevent_actions definition

```
  CREATE TABLE `bizevent_actions` (
    `BizEvent_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    `action` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `objectBizType` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `objectName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `objectRefClazz` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `objectRefIdAsStr` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `objectRefIdType` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `objectRefVersion` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `targetBizType` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `targetName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `targetRefClazz` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `targetRefIdAsStr` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `targetRefIdType` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `targetRefVersion` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `embedJson` longtext,
    `actions_ORDER` int(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`BizEvent_id`,`actions_ORDER`),
     KEY `IDXa21hhagjogn3lar1bn5obl48gll` (`action`),
     KEY `IDX7agsatk8u8qvtj37vhotja0ce77` (`targetRefClazz`),
     KEY `IDXa7tktl678kqu3tk8mmkt1mo8lbo` (`targetRefIdAsStr`),
     KEY `IDXa22eevu7m820jeb2uekkt42pqeu` (`objectRefClazz`),
     KEY `IDXa33ba772tpkl9ig8ptkfhk18ig6` (`objectRefIdAsStr`),
   CONSTRAINT `FKr9qjs61id11n48tdn1cdp3wot` FOREIGN KEY (`BizEvent_id`) REFERENCES `bizevent`      (`id`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;>
```

By the way we are using Amazon RDS 5.7.33 MySql version. 16 GB RAM and 4 vCPU.

I also did a Explain Extended on the query and below is what it shows. Appreciate any help.

Initially the search of the bizevent_actions didn;t have the indexes defined. I have defined the indexes for them and tried the query but of no use.

[image]

Comment: How many rows do you expect to get from both tables, on average?

Comment: It depends. it would probably return less than 500 rows sometime less than 50 by far.

Comment: try OPTIMIZE TABLE which may help you ..

Comment: You use conditions by right table in WHERE - so replace LEFT JOIN with INNER JOIN.

Comment: How do i continuously optimize the tables which there are so many updates inserts and selects that would running these during the run time.

Comment: I tried the INNER JOIN and still the query takes several minutes. Not much of an improvement

Answer (score 0):

One technique that worked for me in a similar situation was abandoning the idea of JOIN completely and switching to queries by PK. More detailed: find out which table in join would give less rows on average if you use only that table and related filter to query; get the primary keys from that table and then query the other one using `WHERE pk IN ()`.

In your case one example would be:

```
SELECT   
 bizevent0_.id as id1_37_,
 bizevent0_.json as json2_37_,
 bizevent0_.account_id as account_3_37_, 
 ...
FROM BizEvent bizevent0_
WHERE
 bizevent0_.createdOn >= '1969-12-31 19:00:01.0'
   AND bizevent0_.id IN (
     SELECT BizEvent_id
     FROM BizEvent_actions actions1_
     WHERE
        actions1_.action <> 'SoftLock'
        and actions1_.targetRefClazz = 'com.biznuvo.core.orm.domain.org.EmployeeGroup'
        and actions1_.targetRefIdAsStr = '1'
        or actions1_.action <> 'SoftLock'
        and actions1_.objectRefClazz = 'com.biznuvo.core.orm.domain.org.EmployeeGroup'
        and actions1_.objectRefIdAsStr = '1')
ORDER BY
  bizevent0_.createdOn;
```

This assumes that you're not actually willing to select 33+ Mio rows from `BizEvent` though - your code with `LEFT OUTER JOIN` would have done exactly this.

Comment: I did tried that  removing the left outer and making in sub select however not that much of improvement the query still takes several minutes.